# "It is a chair in" my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Can I use "it" instead of "there" to say that "it's a chair there and not something else?
"Next to the door on the left it is a chair."

Comment: No, it's not idiomatic. Sounds very much like a non- native speaker with a limited grasp of the language. **there** is optional. Can be omitted without changing anything.

Comment: I would use "That is a chair and not [some other object]" or "There is a chair in that [specified location]" for the first sentence and "Next to the door on the left is a chair" for the second sentence.

Comment: You need to explain why you want to substitute "it". When a location is specified, "here" "there" etc. should be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native AmE speaker here.

In the first example, you can use "it's a chair there" as a way of emphasizing that a chair, as opposed to a table or dresser, occupies that location.

In the second example, however, you cannot use "it". The sentence would have to be "Next to the door on the left is a chair." The reason is because the subject of "is" is the entire phrase "Next to the door on the left" so since you already have an explicit subject in that slot, you can and should drop the pronoun "it."